# how to add individual elements of multiple arrays (integer) in vb

Tags: arrays, vb.net, integer, addition

Basically I have made a program so that it can read numbers from a file, the three arrays each store the same values, except that for each array the numbers will go up by 1. So if array 1 has the value 1, array 2 will have the value 2 and array 3 will have the value 3. What I want to know is how can I add these values together by their position in the array (in the example earlier 1,2 and 3 were all the first elements of their arrays), divide by three and store them in a new array in visual basic?

Clearer example:

> Program reads the numbers 1,2,3 (example numbers) from a file
>   Stores them in a array
>   Creates two new arrays with the same values in the same dimensions except they have all been increased by 1
>   Add each value from each array at the same position and divide by three
>   Store values in a different array

```
1st array:
1
2
3
2nd array: (add 1)
2
3
4
3rd array (add 2)
3
4
5
final array (add them via their position in the array and divide by 3)
1 + 2 + 3 = 6 / 3 = 2 (1st value)
2 + 3 + 4 = 9 / 3 = 3 (2nd value)
3 + 4 + 5 = 12 / 3 = 4 (3rd value)
```

I've been able to get the numbers into the arrays with the following code:

```
array1 = numbers.ToArray
For Each element As Integer In array1
    Console.WriteLine(element)
Next
Console.ReadLine()
array2 = numbers.ToArray 
For Each element As Integer In array2
    element += 1
    Console.WriteLine(element)
Next
array3 = numbers.ToArray 
For Each element As Integer In array3
    element += 2
    Console.WriteLine(element)
Next
```

The code is able to take the numbers from a list of integers (numbers) and store it accordingly **however what am having trouble with is *adding each number according to it's position in the array*** :/

Any help would be much appreciated guys :)

Comment: If the second and third arrays contain numbers that are 1 and 2 greater than the number in the same position in the first array, then there is no point in having the second and third arrays. To calculate the average of the values in the same position in your three arrays, just add 1 to the value in the first array.

Comment: Ah i see now xD but what if the values in each array ranged from 0,10 how would I calculate the average then?

Comment: The second array will always contain the average of the three numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim array1 As Integer() = {1, 2, 3}
Dim array2 As Integer() = {2, 3, 4}
Dim array3 As Integer() = {3, 4, 5}


Dim elementAvgs(array1.Length - 1) As Double
For n As Int32 = 0 To array1.Length - 1
    elementAvgs(n) = (array1(n) + array2(n) + array3(n)) / 3
Next
```

Comment: The upper bound of the For-statement should be `array1.Length - 1`